# anytime producing NA dates only for dates before the 10th

Tags: r, anytime

I am attempting to read dates from a CSV.  Sample:

```
Date    User 1  User 2
8/1/2019    IN  IN
8/2/2019    IN  Out
8/3/2019    IN  IN
8/4/2019    IN  IN
8/5/2019    IN  IN
8/6/2019    IN  IN
8/7/2019    IN  IN
8/8/2019    IN  IN
8/9/2019    IN  IN
8/10/2019   IN  IN
8/11/2019   IN  IN
```

I thought I had a good method worked out for reading these dates correctly, which was:

```
Vacation <- read.csv("Vacation.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
Vacation$Date <- anydate(Vacation$Date)
```

However, for some reason only dates before the 10th are NA once I convert to date.

```
 [1] NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          
   [7] NA           NA           NA           "2019-08-10" "2019-08-11" "2019-08-12"
  [13] "2019-08-13" "2019-08-14" "2019-08-15" "2019-08-16" "2019-08-17" "2019-08-18"
  [19] "2019-08-19" "2019-08-20" "2019-08-21" "2019-08-22" "2019-08-23" "2019-08-24"
  [25] "2019-08-25" "2019-08-26" "2019-08-27" "2019-08-28" "2019-08-29" "2019-08-30"
  [31] "2019-08-31" NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          
  [37] NA           NA           NA           NA           "2019-09-10" "2019-09-11"
  [43] "2019-09-12" "2019-09-13" "2019-09-14" "2019-09-15" "2019-09-16" "2019-09-17"
  [49] "2019-09-18" "2019-09-19" "2019-09-20" "2019-09-21" "2019-09-22" "2019-09-23"
  [55] "2019-09-24" "2019-09-25" "2019-09-26" "2019-09-27" "2019-09-28" "2019-09-29"
```

Comment: `lubridate::mdy(d$Date)`

Comment: That took care of it, please leave it as an answer if you get a moment so I can mark it answered.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base R

```
as.Date(strptime(d$Date, "%m/%d/%Y"))
```

OR

```
lubridate::mdy(d$Date)
#[1] "2019-08-01" "2019-08-02" "2019-08-03" "2019-08-04" "2019-08-05" "2019-08-06" "2019-08-07"
#[8] "2019-08-08" "2019-08-09" "2019-08-10" "2019-08-11"
```

Answer (score 1):

Worth noting, from the tidyverse is `read_csv()`, that in my experience reads in faster than `read.csv()` and accommodates more non-ideal date formats.

```
library(tidyverse)

Vacation <- read_csv("Vacation.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
            mutate(Date = mdy(Date))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be fixed in the next release as I (belatedly) realized that the Boost date_time library has a different format parameter for this which I am adding:

Example:

```
 R> library(anytime)  # unreleased version, on CRAN in a few weeks
 R> inp <- gsub("-0", "-", format(anydate(20190801) + 0:12))
 R> inp  ## note the single digits
  [1] "2019-8-1"  "2019-8-2"  "2019-8-3"  "2019-8-4"  "2019-8-5"  "2019-8-6"
  [7] "2019-8-7"  "2019-8-8"  "2019-8-9"  "2019-8-10" "2019-8-11" "2019-8-12"
 [13] "2019-8-13"
 R>
 R> anytime(inp)
  [1] "2019-08-01 CDT" "2019-08-02 CDT" "2019-08-03 CDT" "2019-08-04 CDT"
  [5] "2019-08-05 CDT" "2019-08-06 CDT" "2019-08-07 CDT" "2019-08-08 CDT"
  [9] "2019-08-09 CDT" "2019-08-10 CDT" "2019-08-11 CDT" "2019-08-12 CDT"
 [13] "2019-08-13 CDT"
 R>
R> anydate(inp)
  [1] "2019-08-01" "2019-08-02" "2019-08-03" "2019-08-04" "2019-08-05" "2019-08-06"
  [7] "2019-08-07" "2019-08-08" "2019-08-09" "2019-08-10" "2019-08-11" "2019-08-12"
 [13] "2019-08-13"
 R>
```